# Unpermitted parameters while update using Rails 4 and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know this seems like a common issue here, but I have tried all the solutions others seemed working but not on mine, so I'm here for some help.
This is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice:'New User has been successfully created!'}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user}
      else
        format.html { render :new}
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:Email, :Secure_password, :Name, :Role =>[])
  end
```

And my form for the update information is here:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>   
          <ul>
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name, "name" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>  
    <p>
      <%= f.label :role %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :role %>
    </p>   
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I have tried adding this to the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:update)  {|u| u.permit(:email, :name, :role)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:create)  {|u| u.permit(:email, :name, :role)}
  end

end
```

Still giving me the Unpermitted parameters message in the server console:

```
Started PATCH "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-17 10:14:55 -0500
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kjWMoKSuzh5ppY4rtReDGqMeR2OvdNx0eTY8J/VS0ED4YyNmC3NVJGzCw6/V3eUCsMDGtfaN8gt7c2lxOM70DQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"example", "email"=>"user@example.com", "role"=>"student"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: name, email, role
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

What should I do to make this work? Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your params looks like this which doesn't match the parameters whitelisted in users controller those keys are case sensitive, so change them as below :-

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kjWMoKSuzh5ppY4rtReDGqMeR2OvdNx0eTY8J/VS0ED4YyNmC3NVJGzCw6/V3eUCsMDGtfaN8gt7c2lxOM70DQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"example", "email"=>"user@example.com", "role"=>"student"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"1"}

`def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :secure_password, :name, :role)
 end`

Comment: Yes I have updated those, and I can update the role indeed, but it still told me that I have unpermitted parameter  :name

Comment: I know what I did wrong. Shouldn't put "=>[ ]" behind name

Answer (score 1):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :secure_password, :name, :role =>[])
end
```

These shouldn't be capitalised, like you have above.

Comment: Yes that seems like the case, and I can update role now. But I still cannot update name,